# Reason behind displaying/not displaying the spring validation message on the view

Tags: java, spring-boot

I tried to create a validation:

```
@Size(min = 6, message = "min 6 characters needed")
private String name;
```

now, when I use the method (annotated with **POST**) with argument:

```
@Valid LoginDetails loginDetails
```

the error message is not displayed when the validation fails (less than 6 characters entered in the form). But if I used this as the argument:

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("logindetails") LoginDetails loginDetails
```

the error message is displayed - I want to understand why is this happening.

here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
package com.example.validationspring;


import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

public class LoginDetails {

    @NotNull(message = "Username cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "Username must be at least 6 characters")
    private String userName;

    // Standard getters and setters
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

> 

```
package com.example.validationspring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping
    public String showLoginForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("logindetails", new LoginDetails());
        return "loginpage";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String submitLoginForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("logindetails") LoginDetails 
    loginDetails, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginpage";  // If errors, show the form again with validation messages
        }
        // Process the data and redirect (assuming validation passed)
        return "redirect:/success";
    }
}
```

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${logindetails}" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="userName">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" id="userName" />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')}" th:errors="*{userName}">Username Error</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need ModelAttribute annotation to well pass data to view and Valid annotation just to complete object validation with jarkata. you need both to make things work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets compare the two cases -->

When dealing with form submission and validation in Spring MVC, the way you define your controller method parameters significantly affects how the framework binds request parameters to your form backing objects and how it handles validation. Let's compare the two scenarios you mentioned to understand the differences.

***Scenario 1:*** **Using `@ModelAttribute("logindetails") LoginDetails loginDetails`**

When you annotate a method parameter with `@ModelAttribute("logindetails")`, you're giving Spring MVC explicit instructions on how to process the incoming form data and bind it to your model.

1. **Binding**: Spring MVC binds the request parameters to the fields of the `LoginDetails` instance identified by `logindetails` (model attribute). This instance is either retrieved from the model if it already exists (e.g., in your code, it is added in a `GET` request handling method) or created newly if it is not already in the model.
2. **Validation**: When you use `@Valid` next to `@ModelAttribute`, Spring applies the validation constraints defined in `LoginDetails` class to the instance filled with the request data. If there are any constraint violations (e.g., a field is too short, too long, or null when it shouldn't be), these violations are captured and reported.
3. **Error Handling**: If validation fails, the errors are attached to the specific instance of `LoginDetails` referred to as `logindetails` in the model. When you return a view name (like `loginpage`), Spring ensures that the same instance of `LoginDetails` (with the errors) is available in the model when rendering the view. This means the Thymeleaf page can access and display the validation errors using `th:errors` or equivalent.

***Scenario 2:*** **Using `LoginDetails loginDetails` (without `@ModelAttribute`)**

In this case, you're not providing explicit instructions to Spring MVC about how to handle the incoming form data with respect to the model. Here's what happens:

1. **Binding**: Spring MVC still attempts to bind request parameters to the fields of a `LoginDetails` instance. However, this instance isn't explicitly tied to the model with a specific name. It's a method parameter that's populated and then used within the method's scope.
2. **Validation**: You can still use `@Valid` to apply validation constraints to the `LoginDetails` instance. If there are violations, they are captured.
3. **Error Handling**: Here's where the significant difference lies. If validation fails, while the errors are captured, they may not be automatically attached to a model attribute that the view can access. This is because you haven't explicitly told Spring MVC to use a named model attribute. When you return a view name (`*loginpage*` in this case), you need to ensure that you manually add the `LoginDetails` instance (with the errors) back into the model, or the view won't have access to it and won't display the errors. You can add it manually by modification of `if` body:

   ```
   if(error.hasErrors()) {
     model.addAttribute("logindetails", loginDetails);
     model.addAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "logindetails", error);
     return "loginpage";
   ```

#### Detailed Comparison When Validation Fails:

- **ModelAttribute Binding**: With `@ModelAttribute("logindetails")`, the framework clearly knows that the `logindetails` is a named model attribute. It ensures that the instance with validation errors is the one used when rendering the view. Your form can show the errors because the `th:errors` tags are looking at the same `someFormBackingBean` instance in the model.
- **Without ModelAttribute Binding**: Without `@ModelAttribute`, the link between the `loginDetails` parameter and the model is less explicit. If you don't manually add the `loginDetails` (with errors) back to the model before returning the view, the view might not have access to the errors. It might instead have access to a new, error-free instance of `LoginDetails`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is due to the name of the model attribute. If you don't specify the name of the model attribute it will be internally derived from the declared attribute type. Which would be in your case `loginDetails` (as opposite to `logindetails` actually used).

In other words this code is equivalent:

```java
@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginDetails") LoginDetails login
```

```java
@Valid @ModelAttribute LoginDetails login
```

```java
@Valid LoginDetails login
```

Please note: in the above case attribute name used in the template need to be `loginDetails`.

This is my recommended solution - simple and consistent:

```java
@Valid LoginDetails loginDetails
```

```
th:object="${loginDetails}"
```

Comment: So, when it derives the attribute type (in case it is not explicitly mentioned) - it will return a new form binding bean (from the `if` clause) & wouldn't bind the error message to it? I am unable to understand the flow (from binding form data to the form backing object to the returning pf the "logindetails") in case of an error.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus this is what the other answer is saying. But I do not agree. My observation and debugging (Spring Boot 3.2.1) show that the binding and error handling works the same way. With or without ModelAttribute annotation. (Of course the naming is still important)

Comment: All the three statements doesn't seem to work the same way (in context to the code provided in the question).

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus you started a bounty to get more detailed answer to your question. What kind of details are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause provided from **Mar-Z** is correct. However since there is still need for further explanation you can look here.

As documented in [Spring ModelAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-methods/modelattrib-method-args.html)

> Tip
>
> **Using @ModelAttribute is optional.** By default, any parameter that
> is not a simple value type as determined by BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty
> AND that is not resolved by any other argument resolver **is treated as
> an implicit @ModelAttribute.**

So even in absence of ModelAttribute it will still be implicitly used from Spring.

There is a catch though.

If you look in the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c4405104a818ed44feb297b967dbd2cd7d9bdda6/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.java#L81) on how the default name is applied you will see:

> The name of the model attribute to bind to.
> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared attribute type
> (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type), **based on
> the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class
> "mypackage.OrderAddress", or "orderAddressList" for "List<mypackage.OrderAddress>"**.

Your problem occurs because you have in several places (thymeleaf template and code) used as model name the login**d**etails. The class name however is `LoginDetails`. So in absense of `@ModelAttribute` spring will use an implicit one with the name login**D**etails.

The best practice solution here would be to update both the thymeleaf template and your code and use the name **loginDetails** for your model. Then you can try removing `@ModelAttribute`.